# Understanding NotUsed and Done

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am having a hard time understanding the purpose and significance of `NotUsed` and `Done` in Akka Streams.

Let us see the following 2 simple examples:

**Using NotUsed :**

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("akka-streams")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val myStream: RunnableGraph[NotUsed] =
  Source.single("stackoverflow")
  .map(s => s.toUpperCase())
  .to(Sink.foreach(println))

val runResult:NotUsed = myStream.run()
```

**Using Done**

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("akka-streams")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val myStream: RunnableGraph[Future[Done]] =
  Source.single("stackoverflow")
  .map(s => s.toUpperCase())
  .toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.right)

val runResult: Future[Done] = myStream.run()
```

When I run these examples, I get the same output in both cases:

```
STACKOVERFLOW //output
```

*So what exactly are NotUsed and Done? What are the differences and when should I prefer one above the other ?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the choice you are making is between `NotUsed` and `Future[Done]` (not just `Done`).

Now, you are essentially deciding the **materialized value** of your graph, by using the different combinators (`to` and `toMat` with `Keep.right`).
The materialized value is a way to interact with your stream while it's running. This choice does not affect the data processed by your stream, and for this reason you see the same output in both cases. The same element (the string "stackoverflow") goes through both streams.

The choice depends on what your main program is supposed to do after running the stream:

- in case you are not interested in interacting with it, `NotUsed` is the right choice. It is just a dummy object, and it conveys the information that no interaction with the stream is allowed nor needed
- in case you need to listen for the completion of the stream to perform some other action, you need to expose the `Future[Done]`. This way you can attach a callback to it using (e.g.) `onComplete` or `map`.

Comment: `The materialized value is a way to interact with your stream while it's running.` Can you please explain more on this? I am assuming that you are referring to infinite streams here. For eg: an embedded device initiated a connection with the server and is feeding data continuously.  So,in this case do we have a single Future[Done] generated in the end after stream processing is completed ? OR do we have multiple Future[Done] continuously created while the infinite stream is still running ?  contd..........

Comment: ....... What I mean is in case of infinite streams, do we continuously materialize or we only materialize only once in the end with the Sink ? Sorry, the akka-streams doc isn't easy to understand these kind of implementation details and in most of the cases, the provided examples are for simple use cases only.

Comment: It's what you get when you call `.run()`, so it's only one materialized value **per stream**. The stream runs asynchronously, so you get a `Future[Done]` straightaway after your `run()` call. This future completes/fails when the stream completes/fails. If the stream is infinite, it may never complete.